# Stylelint fix in WebStorm

Tags: css, webstorm, stylelint

I configured stylelint in my WebStorm (2018.2.3) in `Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> Stylesheets -> Stylelint`. And I have .stylelintrc in my root.

Right now stylelint successfully underlines errors in my css file. 
But is there a way to fix them also with WebStorm help (without running `--fix` command in console)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I created the external tool in Settings | Tools | External Tools, like this:

[image]

And then added the shortcut keymap for this command in here:

[image]

So now it fixes the whole file on the keymap press

Comment: If anyone is is like me and doesn't know what value to set in the `Program:` field because the value in the image is cropped and could not find the .cmd, use `$ProjectFileDir$/node_modules/.bin/stylelint` (this means check the project root folder, and use the executable inside the node installed dependency)

And if you wanna access the option without creating the keyboard shortcut: right click in the Webstorm editor -> External Tools -> <the tool just created>

Answer (score 15):

Stylelint autofixes are not yet supported, please follow [WEB-25069](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25069) for updates.

You can set up a [file watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.3/settings-tools-file-watchers.html) to have `stylelint --fix` triggered in `Save All`:

[image]

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, change the program to use npx (/home/marksy/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/npx) and in arguments:
stylelint $FileName$ --fix

Comment: Also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50148 for the "latest" on this issue - doesn't seem to be resolved as of this comment's date :(

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Ceate watcher (Settings > Tools > File Wathcers) with settings below:

```
Program                  -    $ProjectFileDir$\node_modules\.bin\stylelint
Arguments                -    $FilePath$ --fix
Outout path to refresh   -    $FilePath$
Working directory        -    $FileDir$
```